# Django LiveServerTestCase appears to reload fixtures between tests

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I'm running this with Django 2.2.5 and Postgres 11

It appears that the Django test framework's LiveServerTestCase reloads fixture data in-between  each test without deleting the previous data.  I come across this with a consistent error:

```
> ./manage.py test functional_tests
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.EE
======================================================================
```

The first test passes but the subsequent tests fail.

The error I get is:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '.../fixtures/unit_test.json': Could not load app.Configuration(pk=1): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "app_configuration_site_id_3124a87d_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (site_id)=(1) already exists.
```

If I comment out and don't load fixtures the 3 tests work perfectly fine.

There is only one record entry with the PK in question in the fixtures.  This tells me that the Test reloads the data and fails because it finds an existing record with the same PK.

Is there a way to tell it to either overwrite the data with the same PKs or ignore (a-la get_or_create)?

Is there a better practice to follow with LiveServerTestCase?

It's frustrating because I can't seem to be able to use this test class with fixtures when I need to.

Any insight is appreciated.

RB

---

Here is the test setup:

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver

class TestHeaderNavigation(LiveServerTestCase):

    fixtures = ['unit_test']

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.selenium = WebDriver()
        self.selenium.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.selenium.get('%s' % (self.live_server_url))

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()
        self.selenium.quit()
```

Comment: Are you using `LiveServerTestCase` with testing driver like Selenium? And another question is could you please show the test code?

Comment: Yes, we are using Selenium with it.  It is however happening with or without Selenium using a fixture with the LiveServerTestCase.  It's happening with the LiveServerTestCase class.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to having a model record that gets automatically generated in a post_save clashing with one that exists in fixture.  It seems to not get rewound in a way that I thought it would between tests.  The post_save uses a "get_or_create()" which is why it does not clash on the first test.  The clash happens on the 2nd test onwards.

Comment: This is likely either a Django bug or a "You need to do it this way..." solution.

Comment: Also, we run different test classes (TestCase) with the same fixtures with the same model code (post_save) without this issue.

Comment: At my point of view, everything look good. Could you please take a look on your app configuration model? Is that the model which you created on your application? http://5minutes.youkidea.com/transactiontestcase-keepdb-django-issues.html this article might give you some clue to solve your problem I think